# how to config android.mk when i need to export several native library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Now i export one native library and my folder is like this :

JNI\ANN*.cpp.

android.mk file is like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ 

LOCAL_MODULE    := libann
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ANN.cpp \
    bd_pr_search.cpp \
    bd_tree.cpp \
    kd_pr_search.cpp \
    kd_split.cpp \
    kd_util.cpp \
    bd_fix_rad_search.cpp \
    bd_search.cpp \
    brute.cpp \
    kd_fix_rad_search.cpp \
    kd_search.cpp \
    kd_tree.cpp \
    kd_dump.cpp \
    perf.cpp\
    sample.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now i want to add some other cpp files and export another native lib. 
for example, i add two files:  graph.h,dijkstra,cpp
how should i config the android.mk file?

Comment: Why do you need to build several libraries? Can't you stuff all native code into one?

Comment: the different library represent different logic and different things. so i want to divide them to different part. Does exist this possibility?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev is right; you should have a very good reason to want more than one native library produced in your project. Also, please disclose what you tried before asking the question, and why this effort failed.

Comment: In C++, there are other ways to separate logic - classes, namespaces, files. Splitting code into libraries isn't a good way to do this. A possibility exists, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: i have choose to incorprate the code to one library. But could you give some sample or hints for export code into several libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
project/
    liba/
        srca.cpp
    libb/
        srcb.cpp 




# TOP_PATH refers to the project root dir (project)
TOP_PATH := $(call my-dir)/.

# Build library a
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_PATH)/liba
LOCAL_MODULE := liba
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := srca.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Build library b
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_PATH)/libb
LOCAL_MODULE := libb
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := srcb.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```